# Is calculus necessary for finding the difference in entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, integration

My book uses calculus to find the difference in entropy of an object with mass m and specific heat capacity s between two states with temperatures $T_1$ & $T_2$.

$dS=\frac{Q}{T}$

$\implies \Delta S=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{Q}{T}$

$\implies \Delta S = \int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\frac{msdT}{T}}$ [m=mass, s=specific heat capacity]

$\implies \Delta S = ms\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\frac{dT}{T}}$

$\implies \Delta S=ms[lnT]_{T_1}^{T_2}$

$\implies \Delta S=ms[lnT_2-lnT_1]$

Now, this is what my book did. I for one believe that calculus is completely unnecessary here.

$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T_2}-\frac{Q}{T_1}$

$\Delta S=Q(\frac{1}{T_2}-\frac{1}{T_1})$

$\Delta S=ms\Delta T(\frac{1}{T_2}-\frac{1}{T_1})$

Am I incorrect?

Comment: Your result doesn't even come close to approximating the correct answer, obtained by integration.  Even at small changes in temperature, it is proportional to the square of the temperature change, rather than the temperature change to the 1st power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are incorrect. The equation $\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T}$ only applies when $T$ is constant. $\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T_2}-\frac{Q}{T_1}$ describes the total entropy change involved with heat transfer between two heat baths, not the entropy change of a single object with a changing temperature.

You can imagine considering $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$ for some $dQ$ that is so small that the temperature doesn't change much, and do this over and over again to approximate an answer. The calculus does exactly this, in the limit that $dQ\to 0$, to arrive at an exact answer.

Comment: "and do this over and over again to approximate an answer." -could you please explain this a bit more? I'm having a lot of trouble visualizing this part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan I'm describing what is essentially a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), approximating integrals by taking the area of a series of rectangles.